# MonkeyTalk Table Row value Verify on iOS

Tags: ios, verification, monkeytalk

I'm using MonkeyTalk to automate iOS testing. I get the following error when I try to verify a value.

Failure:Expected "Joe Smith", but found "(null)"

MonkeyTalk code is:

`Table "Empty list" Verify "Joe Smith" item(1)`

Basically, I have a search for user field that returns a table with a list of users.  I want to verify that the cell has the correct value.

Anyone get this work? Or know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the Perfect answer for you :-)

`Table * Verify "Hydrogen" item(1)`  will work if you using default UITableViewCell TextLabel
`Table * Verify "Hydrogen" detail(1)` will work if you using default UITableViewCell DetailTextLabel

else you have very nice way to do it.

[MonkeyTalk : Verify custom UITableViewCell Label text without select the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304129/monkeytalk-verify-custom-uitableviewcell-label-text-without-select-the-cell)

Answer (score 0):

For custom list you can do this by varifying all labels in loop. Like this:

```
    var i=1;
    while(i)    
    {    
       try    
       {    
         app.label.verify("Joe Smith","value","Label doesn't match.");    
         i++;    
       }    
       catch(err)    
       {    
         app.debug().print("No More Labels in Table");    
       }    
   }
```